# Magento 2, after data migration, product page blank, products showing in category list view

Tags: magento2, migration

I have an issue with migrating a store from Magento 1 to Magento 2.
All the data seems to be properly migrated, I can see all the products and associated images and categories in the backend and frontend.
The issue is when I try to open the product page the HTML content is not shown.
It's not a 404, when looking at the source, the header data is correct for the item.
The issue is with the body, it doesn't populate it with data.

Comparing to a working Magento 2 product page, it is missing both scripts and the html elements that should be in the body.

This it the end of the product page source:

```
<body data-container="body"
         data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://192.168.128.109/pub/static/version1586258559/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"}}'
       itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope" class="catalog-product-view product-kanister-5-l page-layout-no-layout-updates">
           </body>
</html>
```

The issue persists no matter what theme I use.

Any ideas what to investigate?

Comment: Managed to solve the issue  by running the following: ```update catalog_product_entity_varchar set value=NULL where attribute_id=107;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a broken reference. Even though I was using the same theme, it completely blocked rendering of the product page.

I managed to fix it by editing the DB,  catalog_product_entity_varchar table with the following:
`update catalog_product_entity_varchar set value=NULL where attribute_id=107`

If you have similar issue, try and create a new product manually and compare the db entry.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, it could be about layout setting of your theme. Or if you have integrated third party modules, try to disable them and fix the problem.